# Can someone tell me why the math is not printing?

Tags: c

I am composing a code that gives the user the total of their package after weight and mileage is calculated. It was working before but after I made minor changes anything that weighs over 2lbs is not printing out anything. Why is this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int weight;
    int miles;
    double mileCost;
    int segment;
    int remainder;

    printf("Charge by weight:(We don't tale packages over 10lbs\n");
    printf("\n 1-2 lbs: $1.50\n 3-6 lbs: $3.70\n 7-10 lbs: $5.25\n ");
    printf("Enter your package's weight:\n");
    scanf("%d", &weight);


    printf("Charge by mile: \n");
    printf("$1.50 for every 500 miles\n");
    printf("Enter the total miles for your package:\n");
    scanf("%d", &miles);

    if(miles == 0 && weight == 0 && weight < 10){
        printf("Invalid entry! Try Again.");
    }

    segment= miles / 500;
    remainder = miles % 500;    
    if(remainder > 0)
        remainder = 1;

    if(weight <= 2){
        mileCost = 1.50 * (segment + remainder);
        printf("The charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
    }
    if(weight > 2 && weight >= 6){
        mileCost = 3.70 * (segment + remainder);
        printf("The charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
    }
    if(weight > 6 && weight >= 10){
        mileCost = 5.25 * (segment + remainder);
        printf("The charge for your package is: %f\n", mileCost);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your conditional operator is pointing the wrong way in the last two if statements, is all. Should be ```weight <= 6``` and ```weight <= 10``` shouldn't it?

Comment: `weight == 0 && weight < 10` - this will be true only if `weight` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

You have your upper bounds written with greater than or equal to `>=` instead of less than or equal to `<=`:

```
if(weight > 2 && weight >= 6){
if(weight > 6 && weight >= 10){
```

This should have been

```
if(weight > 2 && weight <= 6){
if(weight > 6 && weight <= 10){
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
if(weight > 2 && weight >= 6){
```

1) this should be preceeded by `else` so it is not even looked at if weight is <= 2

2) the statement should be:

```
else if(weight > 2 && weight <= 6){
```

notice the `<= 6`

3) similar considerations exist for:

```
if(weight > 6 && weight >= 10){
```